# How to get json_encode value inside a jquery variable?

Tags: jquery, json

api:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
    include("includes/config.php");

    $data = array();
    $query = "SELECT product_name FROM inventory group by product_name;";
    $query .= "SELECT name FROM brands;";
    $query .= "SELECT name FROM categories;";

    mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $data[] = array(
                        'products' => $row['product_name']
                    );
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_next_result($con);

    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
                        'products' => $row['name']
                    );
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_next_result($con);

    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = array(
                        'products' => $row['name']
                    );
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con);

    $results = json_encode($data);
    //$json = json_decode($results, true);
    print($results);
?>
```

.js file

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://localhost/leafteaculture/autocomplete-api.php",
    datatype:"JSON",
    success:function(json){
        alert(json);
        /*for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
            var countries = json[i].products;
            alert(countries);
        }*/
    }
});
```

I am update my question. Now, What happen when I hit on url and after success I used alert to check my api data and its work perfectly. Now, My data look like as I mention below:

```
[{"products":"Twinings"},{"products":"Lipton"},{"products":"Dilmah"},{"products":"Fassai"}]
```

If I got data in `var countries` it must look like:

```
["Twinings","Lipton","Dilmah","Fassai"]
```

So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In your php-file, instead of

```
$data[] = array('products' => $row['name'])
```

try the following:

```
$data['products'][] = $row['name']
```

This would result in a JSON that is formatted like this:

```
{"products": ["Red Label Natural Care", ...]}
```

Then you can access the array in your JS-code via

```
json.products
```

Comment: I use your code api works but when `alert(json.products)` nothing will happen @patrickcipot

Comment: No, it can't be the same as in your code in the question, as you've changed the php-parts, haven't you? Can you please try alert(JSON.stringify(json)) and tell me what shows up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to return each product value.

```
var products = [{"products":"Twinings"},{"products":"Lipton"},{"products":"Dilmah"},{"products":"Fassai"}];

console.log(products.map(function(item) {
    return item[Object.keys(item)[0]];
}))
```

Here i'm using the `Object.keys` to get the first key of each product, you could also use `products` directly ( `return item["products"]` instead)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var products = [{"products":"Twinings"},{"products":"Lipton"},{"products":"Dilmah"},{"products":"Fassai"}];
  
  console.log(products.map(function(item) {
   return item[Object.keys(item)[0]];
  }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```